# What is the best way of having a data structure that manages several services?

Tags: android, service

I am developing an android app that creates several services to monitor several actions the user performs throughout the day.

Although to ensure a good architecture and modularity of the application i need to have a manager class that can allow me to add, start, remove, bind and access data from those services.

what would be a good data type and parameters to represent such a thing?

It has to be able to start every service, bind it and create every ServiceConnection.

This is needed so that i can, depending on some conditions of the phone, manage the services that run in the background at a given time

Comment: Why not have a single service that does it all?

Comment: A service that acts as a manager and starts every other service and manages it all? or a service that has the code corresponding to all the services and performs everything? The second sounds a bit messy and a bad way of doing it.

Comment: Both ways can be correct; in the second case you can spawn threads to do the job of the services. It all depends on what you want to do exactly on them.

Comment: Additionally, a single service could have many delegates. What if you think of your "things that monitor" not as services but as delegates. Now you have 1 service that manages multiple delegates. That seems clean to me. I don't know enough about the project to recommend something past that.

Comment: There is no golden solution. You should provide more information about your project. Every class that has "Manager" in its name is a crap. If you want good and modular architecture, use DDD, dependency injection and follow the SRP rule. Each service should have it's own independent interface. Class that does everything (your manager) is for nothing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion I'd go by having one `Service` that would act as a manager and it would start as many `Thread`s or `AsyncTask`s as you would need.

As you probably know, if you don't stop your `Service` prior to stopping your app, it will keep running in the background. This is just a separate component of your app, when the user is interacting directly with some component of your app (the `Activity` mainly), Android will try as much as it can to keep the active process running, and there's unlikely you'll see that app killed as far as there's not something very bad, but when the user no longer interacts with the app, it becomes dispensable relative to other processes.

In other words, it becomes something non-interesting and will have a bigger priority of being killed regarding to your `Service`. Day to day there are more processes leaving `Services` in background so you'll have to handle your `Service` appropiately if you don't want your users ending uninstalling your app.

Even with this inconvenience, I'd prefer this way because even seeming chaotical and messy, there's just **one** controller that handles all the subprocesses and it decides what to execute next in the case you needed to synchronize results, and what is even more important, once your interacting part of your application run, you just need to stop the `Service` once and you know you're stopping all the background part - otherwise, you'd need to keep track of all the `Services` running and stop them one by one.